# File Path to in memory file

Tags: c, posix

I have a `void *buffer` that is an instance of a file in RAM.

The file type is in a format that must be parsed by the API given.

Unfortunately, the only way to open this file type through the API is to supply the API with the file path:

```
sample_api_open(char *file_name, ...);
```

I understand that `shm_open` returns the file descriptor, but the API only takes a file path.

Is there a work around to read this type of file in memory?

Comment: You could write the memory image to a temporary file and open that.  You could perhaps modify or add to the API.  There is no path referencing a location in the process's memory, though.

Comment: There is no standard way to open a file descriptor to in-process memory via path string without going through a loopback such as a unix pipe.

Comment: This is something I have wanted for a long time--the ability to do file I/O on an in-memory buffer. Perhaps a /dev/ram pseudo device?

Comment: Maybe using something like /proc/<pid>/fd/ ?

Comment: Even `memfd_create` (assuming Linux) cannot save you here, I don't think. Good APIs take file handles or descriptors, not names; cf. "dependency injection".

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a work around to read this type of file in memory?

Dump the content of the buffer into a temporary file on `/tmp`.

On the vast majority of modern *NIX systems, the `/tmp` is a synthetic, in-memory file system. Only in case of the memory shortage, the content might hit the disk due to the swapping.

If the amount of the information is too large, to avoid duplication, after dumping the content onto `/tmp`, you can free the local memory and `mmap()` the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using POSIX shared memory, you could open a temporary file and `mmap()` it. Then make the buffer end up in the `mmap()`-ed region so you can finally call the API on the temporary file.